# The ivar layout string format

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, ivar

A class' ivar layout is defined as a `class_ro_t`'s struct `uint8_t` array field (Take a look at http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-runtime-new.h). So, how can it be interpreted? What is the format of the data stored in it?

Comment: Don't stop reading at the first thing youdon'

Answer (score 0):

Here is Apples code for printing Objective-C 2 meta data structures: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-782/otool/print_objc2_32bit.c?txt.